# Regex to keep only first N columns in every line of CSV file

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, regex-negation

I'm using Perl to process a CSV file.

How can I drop everything (except the newline character) on every line starting with the fifth comma?

E.g. `"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,\n"` would become `"a,b,c,d,e\n"`.

```
$entire_csv_file_contents =~ s/what do I write here?//gm;
```

Because the data will not contain quoted fields etc., `Text::CSV` doesn't have to be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
$entire_this_is_not_csv_file_contents =~ s/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+).*/$1/gm;
```

If you don't need perl 5.8.x compatibility, you can use the `\K` escape, so no capturing is necessary (thanks to amon for the suggestion):

```
$entire_this_is_not_csv_file_contents =~ s/^(?:[^,]+,){4}[^,]+\K.*//gm;
```

Also, depending on whether the fields may be empty or not, you should replace the "+" here by "*" (also thanks to amon).

Comment: … also known as `s/^(?:[^,]*,){4}[^,]*\K.*//gm`; I am quite fond of avoiding unneccessary captures. (Also, the `*` quantifier allows empty fields).

Comment: @amon, might that not qualify as a separate answer?

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need a regex for this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $line = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,\n");
my $cutoff = 5;
my $shortened_line = join(',', (split(/,/, $line, $cutoff+1))[0..$cutoff-1]);

print "$shortened_line\n";   # => a,b,c,d,e
```

Comment: Isn't /,/ a regex, too?

Comment: s/regex/substitution operator/;

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex.  You would have to deal with the possibility of quoted fields containing commas or escaped quotes.

Instead, use the Perl module `Text::CSV` to correctly parse the input lines into fields, then output only the fields you are interested in.

Comment: In this context, quoted fields are not a possibility.  Pretend I didn't say CSV?  :)

Comment: Kev: why do you hate the idea of using that module so much? It has a nice interface you don't have to reinvent and experience tells me that that oh so simple format you have to parse now will soon turn into a full-blown nightmare. The next question  you will probably hear is "how do I add colors?".

Comment: @innaM, sometimes I favour modules, but sometimes I prefer less dependencies (if you want to interpret that as "hating that module so much", well...go ahead.  :) )  I wanted to know also because I was curious about the general technique.  If it were HTML or something I might accept the "you're asking the wrong question" answer, but in this case, I have good reasons for not believing this will turn into a "full-blown nightmare".  I'm not sure who would be posing the colours question, but I can assure it, it won't be me...I just wanted a regex to learn from :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perl, but maybe it helps:

```
cut -d, -f1-5 test.csv
```

Comment: It's part of a larger perl script on win32.  I don't have `cut` available.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAscript I've been using this Regex to take

first 8 Columns, including empty values, of a CSV file

(replace last comma "," in result if needed)

```
^(([^,]*,){8})
```

https://regex101.com/r/qtGO5f/3

To get result without CSV HEADER start matching after the first new line (\n)

```
\n(([^,]*,){8})
```

https://regex101.com/r/23jUrP/1